# I have to change static /js/css path after - npm run build #ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I build a react app using CRA. In deployment, we have different static servers to maintain js/css files. So I have to change static URLs after the build(npm run build).
For example,
in .env.staging I set,

```
PUBLIC_URL=http://api-testing.example.com/
```

when,

```
env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build
```

I got "http://api-testing.example.com/" this in my js/css path.
After testing I have to change this url to "http://api-prod.example.com/"
Please help me. Post your ideas.

Comment: maybe you need create new `.env.production` file?

Comment: using ``.env.production`` I can set a path. How can I change after build?